# Закрытие классов базы данных, курсоров

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Подскажите пожалуйста, зачем (и как правильно) закрывать:

1. SQLiteDatabase класс
2. класс курсора (кстати, как себя поведет адаптер, подключенный к закрытому курсору)
3. класс-наследник SQLiteHelper

Какова практика использования? В части - открыл/закрыл объект. Может есть какая-то последовательность закрытия этих объектов?

У меня имеются несколько классов для работы с БД, но в некоторых случаях я подряд несколько раз использовал открытие бд, на что андроид ругается.. поэтому хочу спросить у профессионалов, как правильно делать? Может есть подход, о котором я не знаю просто.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насчет курсоров - сейчас рекомендуется использовать класс `CursorLoader`, который полностью управляет жизненным циклом курсора, следит за его своевременным открытием и закрытием, а так же работает с ним в параллельном потоке, что наилудшим образом сказывается на производительности приложения.
При этом в таком классе можно переопределить метод выборки данных, чтобы избавить себя от необходимости заводить еще и `ContentProvider`, как то требуется в дефолтной реализации.

Насчет закрытия БД.
В одной, очень содержательной, дискуссии, Диана Хакборн (Dianne Hackborn), далеко не последний человек в подразделении андроид гугла, объясняла всем заинтересованным гражданам, что подключение к БД не только не надо закрывать, а что это еще и не очень то хорошо - закрывать это подключение.
При закрытии приложения/класса, использующего подключение к БД, сборщик мусора уничтожит и классы БД и все будет в норме, в противном же случае происходят какие то страшные вещи.

**UPDATE**

[Вот обсуждение на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608498/best-place-to-close-database-connection) - там есть ссылка на дискуссию гугл-груп андроид-разработчиков, где своим мнением делится Марк Мерфи и Диана. Думаю обсуждение на SO тоже будет интересно.

**UPDATE2**

В своих проектах я использую [Realm](https://realm.io/) и вообще не заморачиваюсь с БД SQLite, уже даже и не вспоминаю эти классы-помошники, курсоры, открытия-закрытия , множество всяких оберток и прочий "ужас" ... Все быстро, очень удобно и просто - работаешь, как с ORM (по принципу классов-моделей), но это нативная БД без прослоек и без SQLite

Comment: буду признателен за дискуссию

Comment: а правильным будет если я в майн активити, например, создам статичную переменную типа SQLiteDatabase, при создании иницииализирую ее, например, как getWritable...и пока открыто приложжение, буду использовать ее, а при уничтожении майн активити, закрывать... ну, или не закрывать вовсе. и наследника SQLiteHelper тоже закрывать не буду?

Comment: @evp Когда я работал с SQLite, я делал класс-синглтон для работы с БД, инициализировал его в наследнике `Application` и закрывал его там же - когда закрывалось все приложение. Не припомню, чтобы были какие то проблемы с утечками памяти при такой реализации

Comment: спасибо. Так и сделаю

Comment: Почему не Hibernate?

Comment: @Alex78191 потому что это Android, он не очень дружит с Hibernate

Comment: @pavlofff в чем выражается?

Comment: @Alex78191 в несопоставимых с мобильным устройством размерах, зависимостях и требованиях, а так же отсутствием поддержки OC Android в принципе, наколько я знаю.

Answer (score 3):

Закрывать нужно из-за устранения проблем с утечкой памяти и производительностью. Адаптер который пытается подключиться к закрытому курсору выдаст ошибку. Закрывать курсор и  SQLiteDatabase классе нужно тогда, когда они закончили работу. В примере ниже я закрываю курсор и бд после того как они отработали:

```
public String getDataFromID(String row, int id) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + ARTICLES_TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String gettingData = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(row));
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return gettingData;
    }
```

Comment: да, но как тогда делать, если этот ID, Который Вы вернули, надо положить в другую таблицу. Например, 
public void updateSomeRow (long id){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = ...
// заполняем строку

// тут находим ID из другой таблицы, чтобы записать с нашу строку
long id2 = getDataFromID(String row, int id); - тут вывалится ексепшен потому как база данных будет заблокирована 

}

я как раз вот так же делаю, как Вы, в каждом методе по возможности открываю и закрываю бд, но как показала практика, это не всегда правильно