# Не получается сохранить чекбоксы в listview c SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-sqlite, cursoradaper

Имеется listview с чекбоксами, база данных и макет CheckableRelativeLayout, в чекбоксах галочки ставятся, при прокрутке ничего не слетает, НО при закрытии приложения, или разрушении фрагмента чекбоксы слетают, а мне нужно просто сохранить чекбоксы, то есть даже при закрытии приложения, выходе из активити чекбоксы должны стоять на своих местах, если были чекнуты.

Я пытаюсь сделать свой адаптер расширяясь из CursorAdapter, но не понимаю, что нужно добавить в адаптер, чтоюы чекбоксы запоминались.

Я примерно догадываюсь, что нужно

1. Создать кастомный адаптер, наследуюясь от CursorAdapter, т.к. работа идет именно с БД, в нем использовать методы bindView, newView.

---

```
public class CursorCountingAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private int layout;
DB db;


public CursorCountingAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, int flag) {
    super(context, cursor, flag);
    this.layout = layout;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView ingr;
    public TextView val;
    public TextView uni;
    public CheckBox myCheck;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ingr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countTvIngr);
        val = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countTvVal);
        uni = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countTvUni);
        myCheck = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.myCheck);
    }
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("getViewTest", "new view");

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    Log.d("valuecheck","bindviewcalled");

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    String ingredients = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_INGR));
    String values = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_VAL));
    String units = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_UNI));
    boolean check = cursor.getInt(Integer.parseInt(DB.COLUMN_CHEKBOX)) > 0;
    int _ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_ID));

    holder.ingr.setText(ingredients);
    holder.val.setText(values);
    holder.uni.setText(units);
    holder.myCheck.setFocusable(false);
    holder.myCheck.setClickable(false);



    holder.myCheck.setTag(new Model(_ID, ingredients, values, units, check));

}

}
```

2. Создать модель данных со всеми элементами, в том числе с чекбоксами

---

```
public class Model {

long id;
String mIngr;
String mVal;
String mUni;
boolean mBox;


public Model(long id, String ingr, String val, String uni, boolean box) {

    this.id = id;
    this.mIngr = ingr;
    this.mVal = val;
    this.mUni = uni;
    this.mBox = box;
}
```

}

3. В основной активности при нажатии на итем listView сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на чекбокс его позиция менялась с 0 на 1 (т.к. boolean переменных в sqlite нет)

Фрагмент CountingFragment - здесь отображается листвью и чекбоксы

---

```
public class CountingFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> { 

private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1; 

public static final int COUNT_LOADER = 2; 

ListView lvData;
DB db;
CursorCountingAdapter scAdapter;
CheckBox mCheckBox;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_counting, container, false);

    lvData = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lvDataCount);
    mCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.myCheck);



    lvData.setItemsCanFocus(false);

    db = new DB(getActivity());
    db.open();


    // формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[] {DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}; 
    final int[] to = new int[] {R.id.countTvIngr, R.id.countTvVal, R.id.countTvUni}; 


    scAdapter = new CursorCountingAdapter(getActivity(), null);

    lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter); 
    registerForContextMenu(lvData);

    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);

    return v;

}

@Override
public void onStart() { 
    super.onStart();
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);

}


public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
        // получаем из пункта контекстного меню данные по пункту списка
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        // извлекаем id записи и удаляем соответствующую запись в БД
        db.delRec(acmi.id);
        // получаем новый курсор с данными
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(COUNT_LOADER).forceLoad();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    db.close();
}


@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    switch (id){
        case COUNT_LOADER:
            String name = getArguments().getString("name"); //строка для получения аргументов создается в onCreateLoader
            return new CursorLoaderCount(getActivity(), db, id, name);
    }

    return null;
}



@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
    scAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}


static class CursorLoaderCount extends CursorLoader {
    Cursor cursor;
    final int LoaderId;
    DB db;
    String name;

    public CursorLoaderCount(Context context, DB db, int id, String name) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
        LoaderId = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {

        switch (LoaderId){

            case COUNT_LOADER:
                cursor = db.getIngrNew(name);
                break;
        }

        return cursor;
    }
  }

}
```

Я понимаю, что ошибок достаточно, и для меня это комплексная проблема, поэтому прошу хотя бы подскажите в каком направлении идти, весь SOF перелопатил, из каждого поста беру какие то моменты, и каша получается в голове.

База данных (по моему я неправильно сохдаю столбец для чекбоксов)

```
public class DB {


    private static final String DB_NAME = "mealsDbb"; 
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1; 
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "myMeals";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEAL = "mealing";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMG = "img";
    public static final String COLUMN_INGR = "ingr";
    public static final String COLUMN_VAL = "val";
    public static final String COLUMN_UNI = "uni";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMGV3 = "img3";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHEKBOX = "myCheck";




    //private static String DB_DELETE = "drop table " + DB_TABLE + ");";


    private static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    COLUMN_IMG + " integer, " +
                    COLUMN_MEAL + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_IMGV3 + " integer, " +
                    COLUMN_INGR + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_VAL + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_UNI + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_CHEKBOX + " integer" +
                    ");";

    private final Context mCtx;


    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DB(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
    }


    public void checkedTrue (int position){
        mDB.execSQL("UPDATE " + DB_TABLE + " SET " +  COLUMN_CHEKBOX + " = '1' WHERE _id = " + position);
    }

public void checkedFalse (int position){
    mDB.execSQL("UPDATE " + DB_TABLE + " SET " +  COLUMN_CHEKBOX + " = '0' WHERE _id = " + position);
}


    // открыть подключение
    public void open() {
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // закрыть подключение
    public void close() {
        if (mDBHelper != null) mDBHelper.close();
    }

    // получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_MEAL, DB.COLUMN_IMG, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }


    public Cursor getMeal () {
        //return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_MEAL}, null, null, null, null, null);

        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_MEAL, COLUMN_IMGV3}, null, null, COLUMN_MEAL, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getIngr () {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_MEAL, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, null, null, /*COLUMN_MEAL + " LIKE ?", Arrays.toString(new String[]{String.valueOf(name)}),*/ null, null, null);
    }

public Cursor getIngrNew (String name) {
    return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI}, DB.COLUMN_MEAL + " = ?", new String[]{name}, null, null, null);
}




// добавить запись в DB_TABLE
    public void addRec(int img, int img3, String mealing, String ingr, String val, String uni, int checkbox) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_UNI, uni);
        cv.put(COLUMN_VAL, val);
        cv.put(COLUMN_INGR, ingr);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MEAL, mealing);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, img);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMGV3, img3);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CHEKBOX, checkbox);

        mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    // удалить запись из DB_TABLE
    public void delRec(long id) {
        mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }


    // класс по созданию и управлению БД
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                        int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        // создаем и заполняем БД
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


        }
    }

}
```

Лэйаут item_counting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/myCheck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/customcheckbox_background"
    android:button="@drawable/customcheckbox"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countTvMeal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/myCheck"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myCheck"
    android:textSize="18sp">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countTvIngr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/countTvMeal"
    android:text=""

    android:textSize="18sp">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countTvVal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/countTvIngr"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="18sp">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countTvUni"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/countTvVal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="18sp">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345). Там реализован аналогичный алгоритм, только вместо чекбоксов - отметки избранного

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы состояния чекбоксов сохранялись, их нужно сразу при изменении записывать в БД (смотрите комментарии к коду):

```
public class CountingFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    public static final int COUNT_LOADER = 2;
    ListView lvData;
    DB db;
    CursorCountingAdapter scAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_counting, container, false);
        lvData = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvDataCount);
        db = new DB(getActivity());
        db.open();

        scAdapter = new CursorCountingAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        lvData.setAdapter(scAdapter);
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(COUNT_LOADER, null, this);

        lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // получаем текущее состояние чекбокса из БД
                boolean isCheck = scAdapter.isChecked();

                // меняем в БД состояние на противоположное
                db.changeChecked(id, isCheck? 0: 1);

                // обновляем данные в курсоре для отображения изменений в списке
                getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(COUNT_LOADER).forceLoad();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.content.Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        String name = getArguments().getString("name");
        return new CursorLoaderCount(getActivity(), db, id, name);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(null);

    }


    static class CursorLoaderCount extends CursorLoader {
        final int LoaderId;
        Cursor cursor;
        DB db;
        String name;

        public CursorLoaderCount(Context context, DB db, int id, String name) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
            LoaderId = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {

            switch (LoaderId) {

                case COUNT_LOADER:
                    cursor = db.getIngr(name);
                    break;
            }
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

ps:для тестов из кода исключена работа с контекстным меню

В адаптере нам нужно установить автообновление списка и организовать отображение отметок чекбоксов в соответствии с записями в БД (смотрите комментарии к коду):

```
 class CursorCountingAdapter  extends CursorAdapter {

    public CursorCountingAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 1); // значение 1 - автообновление списка при изменении курсора
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView ingr;
        public TextView val;
        public TextView uni;
        public CheckBox myCheck;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            ingr = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countTvIngr);
            val = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countTvVal);
            uni = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countTvUni);
            myCheck = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.myCheck);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_counting, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        String ingredients = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_INGR));
        String values = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_VAL));
        String units = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_UNI));

        // получаем состояние отметки из БД
        boolean isCheck = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_CHEKBOX)) > 0;

        holder.ingr.setText(ingredients);
        holder.val.setText(values);
        holder.uni.setText(units);

        // устанавливаем состояние отметки из БД
        holder.myCheck.setChecked(isCheck);
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {

        boolean isCheck = getCursor().getInt(getCursor().getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_CHEKBOX)) > 0;
        return isCheck;
    }
}
```

класс для работы с БД пришлось немного изменить, так как там были некоторые ошибки:

```
class DB {
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_MEAL = "mealing";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMG = "img";
    public static final String COLUMN_INGR = "ingr";
    public static final String COLUMN_VAL = "val";
    public static final String COLUMN_UNI = "uni";
    public static final String COLUMN_IMGV3 = "img3";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHEKBOX = "myCheck";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "mealsDbb";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "myMeals";
    private static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                    COLUMN_IMG + " integer, " +
                    COLUMN_MEAL + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_IMGV3 + " integer, " +
                    COLUMN_INGR + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_VAL + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_UNI + " text, " +
                    COLUMN_CHEKBOX + " integer" +
                    ");";

    private final Context mCtx;


    private DBHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DB(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
    }


    public void changeChecked(long id, int check) {

        // записываем состояние чекбокса в БД
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_CHEKBOX,check);
        mDB.update(DB_TABLE, values, "_id=" + id, null);
    }

    // открыть подключение
    public void open() {
        mDBHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mDB = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // получить все данные из таблицы DB_TABLE
    public Cursor getAllData() {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_MEAL, DB.COLUMN_IMG, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI, DB.COLUMN_CHEKBOX}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }


    public Cursor getMeal() {

        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_MEAL, COLUMN_IMGV3}, null, null, COLUMN_MEAL, null, null);
    }


    public Cursor getIngr(String name) {
        return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, new String[]{COLUMN_ID, DB.COLUMN_INGR, DB.COLUMN_VAL, DB.COLUMN_UNI, DB.COLUMN_CHEKBOX}, DB.COLUMN_MEAL + " = ?", new String[]{name}, null, null, null);
    }


    // добавить запись в DB_TABLE
    public void addRec(int img, int img3, String mealing, String ingr, String val, String uni, int checkbox) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_UNI, uni);
        cv.put(COLUMN_VAL, val);
        cv.put(COLUMN_INGR, ingr);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MEAL, mealing);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMG, img);
        cv.put(COLUMN_IMGV3, img3);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CHEKBOX, checkbox);

        mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    // удалить запись из DB_TABLE
    public void delRec(long id) {
        mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }


    // класс по созданию и управлению БД
    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                        int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        // создаем и заполняем БД
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }

}
```

Для того, чтобы клик отрабатывал по всему айтему, для корневого контейнера необходимо установить параметр `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, а чекбокс заблокировать для кликов:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/myCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countTvMeal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countTvIngr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countTvVal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countTvUni"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

PS: в коде вопроса было множество мелких ошибок, поэтому лучше копировать код из ответа целиком.
PPS: есть мнение, что закрывать подключение к БД [не требуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427870/177345)

Comment: Спасибо, Ваше решение работает.