# Как вывести данные из базы данных в listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Имеется база данных и активити с компонентом listview как из готовой базы вывести в listview элементы из таблицы?
Базу подключаю вот так

```
public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Busstops.sqlite"; // Название файла с БД
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;            //Версия БД
    private static final String SP_KEY_DB_VER = "db_ver";
    private final Context mContext;

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String DB_NAME) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Инициализация БД. Создание новой если ранее не существовала.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        if (databaseExists()) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            int dbVersion = prefs.getInt(SP_KEY_DB_VER, 1);
            if (DATABASE_VERSION != dbVersion) {
                File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
                if (!dbFile.delete()) {
                    // Log.w(TAG, "Невозможно обновить БД");
                }
            }
        }
        if (!databaseExists()) {
            createDatabase();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Проверка существования файла БД. Если существует - возвращает true.
     * @return
     */
    private boolean databaseExists() {
        File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    /**
     * Создание БД, копирование файла из Assets.
     */
    private void createDatabase() {
        String parentPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getParent();
        String path = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();

        File file = new File(parentPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdir()) {
                //  Log.w(TAG, "Невозможно создать папку БД");
                return;
            }
        }

        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            os = new FileOutputStream(path);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            os.flush();
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt(SP_KEY_DB_VER, DATABASE_VERSION);
            editor.commit();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                          int newVersion) {
    }
}
```

и вот код активности

ListView lv1;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actstop1);

        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм такой:

1. Создаете адаптер для `ListView` на основе `CursorAdapter`. Используете уже готовый `SimpleCursorAdapter`, если его функциональность вас устраивает или пишите собственный кастомный адаптер-наследник `CursorAdapter`.
2. Делаете класс-хелпер на основе класса `SQLiteOpenHelper` включающий GRUD-операции с вашей базой данных (добавление, удаление, обновление и запросы (чтение) в БД.
3. Получаете выборку (`Cursor`) из БД через GRUD-операции созданного в п.2 класса (метод `guery()`)
4. Cозданный в п.1 адаптер подключаете к списку `ListView` и передаете полученный курсор.

Для взаимодействия между адаптером и БД настоятельно рекомендуется [использовать класс `CursorLoader`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427870/177345)

[Пример реализации списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345) ListView с заполнением из базы SQLite