# Как правильно закрывать базу данных (вызывать SQLiteDatabase.close)

Tags: android, sqlite

В классе, наследуемом от SQLiteOpenHelper есть метод, который выполняет вставку данных в таблицу

```
...

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(FIELD_NAME, 123);
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

...
```

следует ли в этом же методе закрывать базу

```
db.close();
```

или же закрытие нужно делать как-то по другому?

Comment: Есть авторитетное мнение, что этого вообще [делать не нужно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427870/177345)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. А вообще нормальный ход. В документации на метод getWritableDatabase **Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database**, а оказывается при этом _происходят какие то страшные вещи_