# Закрытие и открытие базы SQlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Здравствуйте.
Есть приложение, 5 активити, каждая работает с БД.
Также в `MainActivity` есть несколько `AsyncTask`, которые работают с БД.

Где правильно открывать соединение с БД, и где его закрывать.

Сейчас я в каждой активити делаю:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Ну и нигде не делаю `database.close()` наверное это не верно?

Comment: есть авторитетное мнение, что [вполне верно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427870/177345)

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный паттерн, предусмотренный системой это освобождение ресурсов в `Activity.onDestroy()` ну или в `Activity.onStop()`

Есть еще способ: закрывать в `finalize()` - но мне этот способ меньше нравится - попахивает каким-то антипаттерном.